# Silent installation of git through use of .bat file on Windows

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, installation, silent

I am currently working on a Windows batch file that will allow me to silently install git (the executable for which will be placed in the folder that the .bat file will be running from) in a pre-specified location on the file system.

I've found this article which seems to provide some suitable advice:

https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Silent-or-Unattended-Installation

However, I'm not entirely sure what parameters I would need to mention in my LOADINF file. I would like to pre-define the options that the user would manually select throughout the various stages  of installation, so that it can run through from start to finish without prompting anything from the user.

Can anyone help or point me to a place where I can find these parameters and their available values?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file, for eg. `my-config.cnf` (or `my-config.ini`) with the following content:

```
[Setup]
Lang=default
Dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git
Group=Git
NoIcons=0
SetupType=default
...
<other options as shown in the msysgit wiki>
```

Now, in the batch file, when you execute the installation file (say `msysgit-install.exe`), use `/LOADINF` as follows:

```
msysgit-install.exe /SILENT /LOADINF="my-config.cnf"
```

Comment: Could you please point me to the location within the wiki where these options are shown? I can't seem to find them anywhere.

Comment: @ct2602 _You can also load install parameters from a file with /LOADINF="filename", and you can record parameters to a file using /SAVEINF="filename"_.

Comment: I'm talking about this part: <other options as shown in the msysgit wiki>

Comment: @ct2602 ah, here https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/install.iss

Comment: On the msysgit wiki page mentioned by @hjpotter92, see flag /SAVEINF="my-config.cnf". From the cmd line use this flag to record the settings of a non-silent run. Then use the config file for silent install. Very useful.